# How to get the size of NSImageView which is the sender after dropping a picture on it

Tags: objective-c, size, nsimageview

In my project I have an `NSImageView` and I drop a picture from the finder on it. In an `IBAction` I want to take care if the picture size is bigger than the dimensions of the `NSImageView` as shown below.

I hoped that `sender.size` or `sender.size.x` or `sender.size.width` would give me the size of the `NSImageView` **imageDropped** but it doesn't.

Any ideas how I can get the dimensions of the `NSImageView`?

```
- (IBAction)imageWasDropped:(id)sender {
   NSImage *theImage = [imageDropped image];

   NSLog(@"%@", sender); // this returns <NSImageView: 0x10011d210>

   NSSize _dimensions = [theImage size];

  if (_dimensions.width > sender.size){

  }

   [imageOriginal setImage:theImage];
   [picture_1 setImage:theImage];

}
```

Comment: I'm not getting exactly what are you trying to explain? do you want the size of your NSImageView (the sender ) ???

Comment: Exactly. In case the image size is bigger than the NSImageView I want to adapt the the image size to NSImageView size.

Comment: Check the answer and please inform, if it works or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very Simple, `_imageView` the outlet name of that imageWell where you drop or display your image.

```
NSLog(@"%f, %f", [[_imageView image]size].height, [[_imageView image]size].width);
```

EDIT:

For imageWell Size:

```
NSLog(@"Image well size is  :%f x %f",[_imageView frame].size.height, [_imageView frame].size.width);
```

Comment: Yes, that´s it. And you are right, it´s really easy :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I got to correct myself. I don´t need the the size of the dropped image, I already have that. I need the size of the imageWell where the picture was dropped on. Something like sender.bounds